# Automapper map propeprties to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I'm new with AutoMapper and have problems with mapping.

My source object:

```
public class SourceEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<object> List1 {get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<object> List2 {get; set; }
}

public class DestEntity
{
    public List<SubDestinationEntity> DestinationObjects { get; set; }
}

public class SubDestinationEntity
{
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<object> Objects {get; set;}
}
```

I can't figure out how can a map mu SourceEntity lists to List.
I mean, `DestinationObjects` should contain `SubDestinationEntity` that contains Source lists in `Objects` collection

**UPD**

Manualy this looks like:

```
var destItem=new DestEntity();
if(sourceItem.List1.Any())
{
    destItem.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity
      {
         Title="Some text 1",
         Objects=sourceItem.List1 
      }
}
if(sourceItem.List2.Any())
{
    destItem.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity
      {
         Title="Some text 2",
         Objects=sourceItem.List2
      }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the expected outcome is? How would you manually map it?

Comment: @MichalCiechan Add an update

Comment: @Gleb What automapper configuration have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no naming convention and no one-to-one relationship property mappings between `SourceEntity` and `DestEntity`, you have two otpions:

### Using constructor mapping

For this you need to add a constructor to your `DestEntity` like below:

```
public DestEntity(IEnumerable<object> list1, IEnumerable<object> list2)
{
    this.DestinationObjects = new List<SubDestinationEntity>();
    if (list1.Any())
    {
        this.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity
        {
            Title = "Some text 1",
            Objects = list1
        });
    }
    if (list2.Any())
    {
        this.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity
        {
            Title = "Some text 2",
            Objects = list2
        });
    }
}
```

After that create your mapping like that:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestEntity>(MemberList.None)
   .ForCtorParam("list1", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.List1))
   .ForCtorParam("list2", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.List2));
```

**Side Note:** You can avoid using `.ForCtorParam()` if parameters of your constructor match the names of properties on your source type. You only need them when parameters don't match.

### Using ConstructUsing method

If you don't want to modifiy `DestEntity` class by adding a new constructor you can use `ConstructUsing` method like below:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestEntity>(MemberList.None)
   .ConstructUsing(sourceItem =>
   {
       var destItem = new DestEntity
       {
           DestinationObjects = new List<SubDestinationEntity>()
       };
       if (sourceItem.List1.Any())
       {
           destItem.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity
           {
               Title = "Some text 1",
               Objects = sourceItem.List1
           });
       }
       if (sourceItem.List2.Any())
       {
           destItem.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity
           {
               Title = "Some text 2",
               Objects = sourceItem.List2
           });
       }

       return destItem;
   });
```

I prefer using the first version the one that uses constrructor mapping because I don't want to put a lot of logic into mapping configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
CreateMap<SourceEntity, DestEntity>()
.AfterMap((src, dest) =>
{
    if (src != null)
    {
        dest = new DestEntity()
        {
            DestinationObjects = new List<SubDestinationEntity>()
        };
        dest.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity()
        {
            Title = "Some text 1",
            Objects = src.List1
        });
        dest.DestinationObjects.Add(new SubDestinationEntity()
        {
            Title = "Some text 2",
            Objects = src.List2
        });
    }
});
```